# How can i fix this error when i run sudo apt-get update command?

Tags: updates

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow these links, you can find out they are indeed missing. There is, however, a repo for precise. So I would suggest looking into `/etc/apt/sources.list` (Alt+F2 - `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`) for this repository line and changing there `raring` to `precise`. Then `sudo apt-get update` one more time to see if this made desired effect.